# Why does my program run without parameters inside the functions' parenthesis?

Tags: python, function, parameters

I am going to ask probably a very silly question. I designed a code that looks like the following:

```
import pandas as pd 
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def menu():
   print("[1]: Favorite color") 
   print("[2]: Number of cats")

#Option1
def FavColor():
   sns.countplot(x= "Color", data = main_data)
   plt.show()

#Option2
def NumCats():
   sns.countplot(x= "Cats", data = main_data)
   plt.show()

#Main Code

try:
   main_data = pd.read_csv("DATAFIN.csv")
except IOError:
   print("Error while trying to open the file")
else:
   menu()
   option = int(raw_input())
   if option == 1:
         FavColor()
   elif option == 2:
         NumCats()
```

main_data looks like this:

```
    Color   Cats
1    Blue      1
2    Yellow    2
3    Blue      2
4    Red       1
5    Blue      3
```

Now, the "problem" is that my program runs exactly as it should. I just realized, however, that all of my functions, options(), Option1() and Option2(), do not have parameters inside the parenthesis. This is due to me forgetting to do so, but my understanding was that my functions should not work without me giving them the parameters that needed to be used.

For example, if Option1 had to use a precise dataframe I should have written Option1(dataframe).

Everything that my functions need to you is defined in the main code, which you go through before calling the functions, so maybe that's the reason. But is it wrong not to put the parameters inside? Does it make my program less efficient?

Comment: First of all, python2 is end of life, and you shouldn't be using it. Second, if you're using an undefined variable Python will complain as such, so you need to show a [mcve] of your actual code

Comment: @OneCricketeer sorry! I just finished my edit. And thank you very much for the feedback. I know that python2 is a mistake, but I have been told to use it since the rest of the class was using it. I will upgrade soon

Comment: So, when you say "runs as it should" - you're able to get a seaborn plot just fine? Are you running this code in a Jupyter notebook environment where a reference to `main_data` might already exist? And your teacher should know Python3 has been available over a decade now

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes, I get the plots just fine and I'm sure they are also correct. I'm running it in Visual Studio Code, but main_data is not defined before running the code. In my environment other than my .py code I only have the DATAFIN.csv file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just happen to be referring to a global variable

Here's a simpler example

```
def foo():
    print(x) 
    
x = 2
foo()
```

x could be defined before or after the function; the function definition captures the closure of the variable reference, not the variable itself

On the other hand, if you defined a main function with local variables, it wouldn't work

```
def foo():
    print(x) 
    
def main():
    x = 2
    foo() 

main()
```

In general, global variables should be avoided, and therefore parameters should be used, which are just references and the overhead of the memory space allocated for function parameters is negligible

Comment: Thank you so much! This means that if, for any reasons, my main code was a function, the whole program would not run. Is it correct? Thank you again for your help.

Comment: You could still read the file outside of the main function, but the issue is variable scoping more than anything

Comment: Got it. Thank you again :)

Answer (score -1):

The empty parentheses indicate that it has no parameters.

Defining a new function does not make the function run.

Comment: Thank you! But I still don't understand. My program works without any problem, exactly as if I put the parameters inside the parenthesis. How is that possible? Here I wrote a simplified version of my code, but actually every function is about 5-10 lines long and they all work.

Comment: @mcnew Then you need to post the **exact code** you’re using. The code you’ve posted definitely won’t work since it’s attempting to use a nonexistent variable.